# adding popup submenu items to the submenu

Tags: javascript, jsp, menu, dojo

I want to create popup submenu items for the submenu. 
Please find the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/nw9tU/353/.
I have a menubar and on click of it, it shows the submenu items, when i mouse over on Save submenu item, it has to popup other 2 submenu items as Save ALL and Save AS. Please suggest how can i add popup submenu items to the submenu item.

Please find the code below:

```
require(["dijit/form/DropDownButton", "dijit/DropDownMenu", "dijit/MenuItem", "dojo/dom", "dojo/domReady!"],
        function(DropDownButton, DropDownMenu, MenuItem, dom){
    var menu = new DropDownMenu({ style: "display: none;"});
    var menuItem1 = new MenuItem({
        label: "Save",
        iconClass:"dijitEditorIcon dijitEditorIconSave",
        onClick: function(){ alert('save'); }
    });
    menu.addChild(menuItem1);

    var menuItem2 = new MenuItem({
        label: "Cut",
        iconClass:"dijitEditorIcon dijitEditorIconCut",
        onClick: function(){ alert('cut'); }
    });
    menu.addChild(menuItem2);

    var button = new DropDownButton({
        iconClass:"dijitEditorIcon dijitEditorIconCut",
        name: "programmatic2",
        dropDown: menu,
        id: "progButton"
    });
    dom.byId("dropDownButtonContainer").appendChild(button.domNode);
});
```

I'm using dropdownButton and DropDownMenu API, as i need to show an icon for the menu item instead of display name as shown in the above fiddle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should take a look at [this](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dijit/Menu.html) to give you an idea of what tools you'll need to build a popup submenu.

Basically, you'll need to create a Menu with MenuItems and then add a pop-up menu item to your original DropDownMenu. See the code below:

```
    var saveMenu = new Menu();
    var saveAllItem = new MenuItem({
        label: "Save All",
        onClick: function () {
            alert('save all');
        }
    });
    var saveAsItem = new MenuItem({
        label: "Save As",
        onClick: function () {
            alert('save as');
        }
    });
    saveMenu.addChild(saveAllItem);
    saveMenu.addChild(saveAsItem);
    menu.addChild(new PopupMenuItem({
        label: "Save",
        iconClass: "dijitEditorIcon dijitEditorIconSave",
        popup: saveMenu
    }));
```

And you can also see an updated Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/nw9tU/355/